# How to detect focus in children from a parent widget

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout, focus

In flutter,

1. How can a parent widget know if a child among many children widgets has received focus? For example, Can we know if a child in a `Row` widget's children has received focus?
2. Can I detect this focus before the child widget receives it?

Comment: Can't this be achieved using FocusNode on the widgets with a listener?

Comment: Possible but this method has a few issues. One problem would be: The child must accept `FocusNode` or have `onFocusChange` callback parameter, for ex: InkWell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends on your take and which architecture you wanna follow.
This snippet that I'm posting uses NotificationListener, a custom notification and a custom child widget. This might work for an application like a print or a callback, but you might need to change the architecture and use a state management tool to achieve greater things.

Parent Widget class:

```
class MyParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<FocusNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        print("New widget focused: ${notification.childKey.toString()}");
        return true;
      },
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
          5,
          (index) => MyChildWidget(
            Key('widget-$index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Child Widget class:

```
class MyChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyChildWidget(Key key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyChildWidgetState createState() => _MyChildWidgetState();
}

class _MyChildWidgetState extends State<MyChildWidget> {
  final node = FocusNode();

  @override
  initState() {
    node.addListener(() {
      if (node.hasFocus) {
        final notification = FocusNotification(widget.key!);
        notification.dispatch(context);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    node.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: node,
    );
  }
}
```

Custom Notification class:

```
class FocusNotification extends Notification {
  const FocusNotification(this.childKey);
  final Key childKey;
}
```

Comment: Your solution requires adding listener to FocusNodes. This might not be good for large, & complicated children. I think if we can check if current widget is parent of focused child using something from `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus`.

Comment: Not true, if you use a ListView.builder you create and dispose of the widgets on the fly. That's why we dispose of the node when we dispose of the widget, to get rid of the subscription created.It won't affect performance and the code will be clean and understandable without overengineering it.

Comment: The initial post asked for a Row example so I provided a Row example, but you can easily see how that can be used in a ListView.builder

Comment: That was a simple case scenario. I need a solution for multiple horizontal pageviews in a list. I'll try to go with the solution you proposed.